# Finding a certain character in Visio and reformating the following text

Tags: vba, excel, visio

Due to a tight timing for one of my projects with Visio I need to look over all the shapes in All the pages for certain character (name it "&") and then change the color of n character after it, so i wrote a code like follow but it does not go through all occurrences in one text block, after it hits the first one the loop exits... I just need help to resolve it my mind is kind of frozen now... sorry if my question is silly

```
Sub test()
    Dim PageObj As Visio.Page
    Dim shpsObj As Visio.Shapes
    Dim shpObj As Visio.Shape
    Dim oShpChar As Visio.Characters

    Set PageObj = ActivePage
    Set shpsObj = PageObj.Shapes

    For Each shpObj In shpsObj
        'Dim iLength As Integer
        Dim iBeginOffset As Integer, iEndOffset As Integer
        Set oShpChar = shpObj.Characters
        Do
            iBeginOffset = InStr(oShpChar.Text, "&test")
            'If iBeginOffset = 0 Then Exit Do    ' # Not found -> end the loop

            iEndOffset = iBeginOffset + 3

            oShpChar.Begin = iBeginOffset
            oShpChar.End = iEndOffset

            oShpChar.CharProps(visCharacterColor) = 9

            oShpChar.Begin = oShpChar.Begin + 1
            oShpChar.End = oShpChar.CharCount
        Loop While (iEndOffset < oShpChar.CharCount)
    Next
End Sub
```

I just tagged it for Excel too since the overall concept is the same...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is found...

Unfortunately Microsoft Visio does not hold the updated value for "Character.Begin" and "Character.End" properties through outer loop, in other word it maintained but not accessible by other method such as"CharProps". so I introduced a counter outside of while loop to keep track of each new value for the mentioned property, hope it helps others to resolve their issue too, it's cost me 7 hours
(I am not a developer so please correct me if I made a mistake in my explanations)!

```
Sub test()
    Set PageObj = ActivePage
    Set shpsObj = PageObj.Shapes

    For Each shpObj In shpsObj
        Dim searchWord As String
        Dim placeHolder As Integer
        Dim iLength As Integer
        Dim iBeginOffset As Integer, iEndOffset As Integer
        Set oShpChar = shpObj.Characters

        searchWord = "&test"
        iLength = oShpChar.CharCount
        Do
            iBeginOffset = InStr(oShpChar.Text, searchWord)
            If iBeginOffset = 0 Then Exit Do    ' searchWord Not found -> end the loop

            iBeginOffset = iBeginOffset + placeHolder
            placeHolder = iBeginOffset + Len(searchWord) - 1
            iEndOffset = iBeginOffset + Len(searchWord) - 1

            oShpChar.Begin = iBeginOffset
            oShpChar.End = iEndOffset

            If iEndOffset > iLength Then Exit Do  ' Preventing the last run 
            oShpChar.CharProps(visCharacterColor) = 9

            oShpChar.Begin = oShpChar.Begin + Len(searchWord) - 1
            oShpChar.End = iLength
        Loop While (iEndOffset < iLength)
    Next
End Sub
```